# Why socket event "new message" calling multiple times ?

Tags: ios, swift, sockets

I'm working on socket first time. I'm getting message from server on event

`socket.on("new message")`

Here are the steps which I'm doing

**Step 1:**

```
socket.connect()
```

On successful connection I'm joining group using

**Step 2:**

```
 socket.emit("joinRoom",groupId,userId,message)
```

and then using

**Step 3:**

```
socket.emit("send message", groupId,userId,mobileNo,type,message)
```

Now once I'm done with sending message the server is broadcasting the same message that is m calling from

```
 override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
    {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.getChatMessage
            { (messageInfo) -> Void in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in


            })
        }

    }
```

And here is method of socket `getChatMessage` which is calling multiple times once I'm done with sending message.

```
    func getChatMessage(completionHandler: (messageInfo: [String: AnyObject]) -> Void) 
    {

        socket.on("new message")
        {
        (dataArray, socketAck) -> Void in


            var messageDictionary = [String: AnyObject]()


            let temp = dataArray[0]


           completionHandler(messageInfo: messageDictionary)
        }

    }
```

I am not getting any clue whether I missing something in my code or the problem with event `socket.on("new message")`. Can anyone suggest me solution for this ?

Comment: why you are writing the getChatMessage in viewDidApperar?

Comment: I tried even in viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear but its giving same results i.e. calling sometimes only once , sometimes 4 times...

Comment: Did you resolve this problem? I have the same issue. -.-

Answer (score 1):

i think the problem is that socket.on("new message") is still listening to events even after the page has disappeared.

so the next time the view appears, getChatMessage is called again and socket.on("new message") is instantiated again, so now there are two things listening to the "new message" emit event.

you can solve this by calling socket.off("new message") in viewwilldisappear